# Simple implementation of a hash function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, hash

I have this function for hashing:

```
func djb2Hash(_ string: String) -> Int {
  let unicodeScalars = string.unicodeScalars.map { $0.value }
  return unicodeScalars.reduce(5381) {
    ($0 << 5) &+ $0 &+ Int($1)
  }
}

djb2Hash("abc") // outputs 193485963
djb2Hash("bca") // outputs 193487083
```

I don't understand why the author used `reduce(5381)` and don't really get the code from the closure that comes next. Can someone explain.

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10696223/5133585) answer your question? You can also see a C implementation of the same algorithm, which should explain a lot.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35472685/5133585) if you don't understand what `&+` means, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72424588/5133585) if you don't understand `reduce`.